# How can I add multiple checkbox values in grid view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

1. **this is my create view in this i use input type=checkbox, but i can'e select multiple value**

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hobby, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
               <div class="col-md-10">
                   <span>WRITING</span><input type="checkbox" groupname="Hobby" name="Hobby" value="WRITING" />
                   <span>DANCING</span><input type="checkbox" groupname="Hobby" name="Hobby" value="DANCING" />
                   <span>COADING</span><input type="checkbox" groupname="Hobby" name="Hobby" value="COADING" />
                   <span>SINGING</span><input type="checkbox" groupname="Hobby" name="Hobby" value="SINGING" />
                   @*<span>DANCING</span> @Html.CheckBox("Hobby", new { @id = "Hobby", @value = "DANCING" })
                       <span>WRITING</span> @Html.CheckBox("Hobby", new { @id = "Hobby", @value = "WRITING" })
                       <span>SINGING</span> @Html.CheckBox("Hobby", new { @id = "Hobby", @value = "SINGING" })
                       <span>COADING</span> @Html.CheckBox("Hobby", new { @id = "Hobby", @value = "COADING" })*@
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hobby, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               </div>
           </div>
   ```
2. **this is my model class , i use SP for add data and i trying to add Multiple checkbox value**

   ```
    public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
           {
               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spaddEmployee", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", emp.FirstName);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", emp.LastName);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", emp.Gender);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.DOB));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", emp.Hobby);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", emp.Photo);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", emp.City);

                   con.Open();
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   con.Close();
               }
   ```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing here?

Comment: I Want to select Multiple CheckBox Value and Add and Show value In Gridview, on avove Code I Only able to add one value @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model will be like

```
Employee{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies{get;set;}   
}

Hobby{
    public string HobbyName{get;set;}
    public string HobbyCode{get;set;}
    public bool IsSelected{get;set;}
}
```

in .cshtml file, you need to apply the for loop to populate the Hobbies checkbox control

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Hobbies.Count; i++)
     {
        <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Hobbies[i].HobbyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Hobbies[i].IsSelected, new {name=@Model.Hobbies[i].HobbyCode,id= @Model.Hobbies[i].HobbyCode})
                                                            <span class="slider"></span>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>Hobbies[i].IsSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
 }
```

In the Hobbies array, you will get the IsSelected flag true or false.

to get the complete list of selected hobbies to apply LINQ queries like :

```
Employee.Hobbies.Where(o => o.IsSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only a single Hobby column on your database, you could use separate IDs for your hobby checkboxes.

Then use a list to get the values of the checkboxes and then join your hobby strings to a single string. Pass that string variable to your SQL function. You could do something like:

```
string myHobbies { get; set; } 

protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<CheckBox> hobbyCheckBoxList = new List<CheckBox>();
     hobbyCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox1);
     hobbyCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox2);
     hobbyCheckBoxList.Add(CheckBox3);
     hobbyCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x=>x.Text);
     myHobbies.Text = string.Join(",", hobbyCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text));
}
```

On your SQL parameter function:

```
 public void AddEmployee(Employee emp, string)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spaddEmployee", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", emp.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", emp.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", emp.Gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.DOB));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", myHobbies);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", emp.Photo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", emp.City);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", myHobbies);    SP Error Occur